# Issue with scrapy : xpath & regex - Regex not working as it should be

Tags: python, regex, xpath, scrapy

here is the context : I am trying to retrieve several dates on a website, and get them in a "doubled list" like this :

```
[[day1start,month1start,year1start,day1end,month1end,year1end], [day2,month2,year2, None, None, None]]
```

Note : in the second date, the date to be retrieve is only one day.

So the dates are organized in the HTML Code as follow :

```
<div class= "eventDate">
<div class="date">
13-Sep-2014
- 14-Sep-2014
</div>
<div class="date">
05-Jul-2014
</div>
<div class="date">
09-Aug-2014
</div></div>
```

So here I would like to use XPATH and REGEX to get exactly as following :

```
[
["13", "Sep", "2014", "14", "Sep", "2014"],
["05", "Jul", "2014", , , ],
["09", "Aug", "2014", , , ]
]
```

So I am using this Xpath to get what I want :

```
dates = response.xpath('//div[@class="eventDate"]/div[@class="date"]/p[1]/text()')
```

it returns me the following when I "print dates" :

```
[<Selector xpath='//div[@class="eventDate"]/div[@class="date"]/p[1]/text()' data=u'\n\t\t\t13-Sep-2014\n\t\t\t\t- 13-Sep-2014\n\t\t'>, <Selector xpath='//div[@class="eventDate"]/div[@class="date"]/p[1]/text()' data=u'\n\t\t\t05-Jul-2014\n\t\t'>, <Selector xpath='//div[@class="eventDate"]/div[@class="date"]/p[1]/text()' data=u'\n\t\t\t09-Aug-2014\n\t\t'>]
```

So I am using THIS REGEX, that IS PERFECTLY working on Rubular, Pythex AND Pythonregex.com !!!!

```
(\d{2})-(\w{3})-(\d{4})(?:.*?-.*?(\d{2})-(\w{3})-(\d{4}))?
```

I noticed the problem came from the ".*" which were not taking into account the "\n"

So I changed it to :

```
(\d{2})-(\w{3})-(\d{4})(?:[\s\S]*?-[\s\S]*?(\d{2})-(\w{3})-(\d{4}))?`
```

Which give the final code :

```
dates = response.xpath('//div[@class="eventDate"]/div[@class="date"]/p[1]/text()').re("(\d{2})-(\w{3})-(\d{4})(?:[\s\S]*?-[\s\S]*?(\d{2})-(\w{3})-(\d{4}))?")
```

My problem :
I get the following table which is not what I want :

```
[u'13', u'Sep', u'2014', u'13', u'Sep', u'2014', u'05', u'Jul', u'2014', u'', u'', u'', u'09', u'Aug', u'2014', u'', u'', u'']
```

Pb is it is in a simple table.. I need it in a double. And it is perfectly workinf on Rubular, Pythex and Pythonregex ! Just not in Scrapy...

1/ Please Help !!!

Also I have sides questions :
2/ How to make the dot match newlines also in Scrapy ?
3/ I noticed that the regex in Scrapy was Non Greedy by default... Is that true and why ?

Comment: Read about [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-contents).

Answer (score 1):

See here http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/77

Your regex is working fine.You need to set `s` flag or `re.DOTALL` to capture `\n`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj this is not OP's original regex.The one which was woring fine on other sites.`s` is needed there.

Comment: So I changed it to :

`(\d{2})-(\w{3})-(\d{4})(?:[\s\S]*?-[\s\S]*?(\d{2})-(\w{3})-(\d{4}))?`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Also I have sides questions : 2/ How to make the dot match newlines also in Scrapy ?

Comment: @vks, you can pass a compiled regex to `.re()`. So you could do `r = re.compile(r"(\d{2})-(\w{3})-(\d{4})(?:[\s\S]*?-[\s\S]*?(\d{2})-(\w{3})-(\d{4}))?", re.DOTALL)` and then `dates = response.xpath(...).re(r)`